# Add multiple combined PHP form data from multiple foreign MSSQL tables to one primary table

Tags: php, html, sql-server, checkbox

I got for this example 7 checkboxes:

```
    <table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;" border="1">
    <tbody>


    <tr style="height: 21px;">
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"><strong>Technologie</strong></td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"></td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"></td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">Tec1</td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">  <input name="Technoloie[]" type="checkbox" value="1" /> </td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">Tec2</td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"><input name="Technoloie[]" type="checkbox" value="1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">Tec3</td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">  <input name="Technoloie[]" type="checkbox" value="1" /> </td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"Tec4</td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">  <input name="Technoloie[]" type="checkbox" value="1" /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">Tec5</td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">  <input name="Technoloie[]" type="checkbox" value="1" /> </td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">Tec6</td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">  <input name="Technoloie[]" type="checkbox" value="1" /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"></td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">Tec7</td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">  <input name="Technoloie[]" type="checkbox" value="1" /> </td>
   <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">Tec8</td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">  <input name="Technoloie[]" type="checkbox" value="2" /> </td>

    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Here is the SQL Table for this Checkbox:

```
+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Tec_ID | Tec1 | Tec2 | Tec3 | Tec4 | Tec5 | Tec6 | Tec7 | Tec8 |RanNr |
+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|      1 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 | 1353 |
|      2 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    0 | 0000 |
|      3 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    1 | 1353 |
|      4 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 | 1123 |
|      5 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    2 | 1353 |
|      6 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    2 | 1353 |
|      7 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    1 | 1993 |
|      8 |    0 |    1 |    1 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 | 1123 |
|      9 |    0 |    1 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    0 | 1353 |
|     10 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    2 | 1366 |
+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

You see already if I check `Tec1` and `Tec5`, I want to get `Tec_ID 1`, so I need a combined checkbox select to get the right `ID` and I want to Insert this Primary Key as an foreign key into a other table to handle with the `id` in further functions.

But atm I have no idea, how I can handle this in MSSQL and PHP Code? Can someone help?

Original table

```
FlashID SAP COB SMT BGA TSOP    LGA
1   102292  0   1   0   2   0
3   102293  0   1   0   2   0
4   102294  0   1   0   2   0
5   102296  0   1   0   0   1
6   102412  0   1   0   1   0
7   102413  0   1   0   1   0
8   102414  0   1   0   1   0
9   102651  0   1   0   2   0
10  102652  0   1   0   2   0
11  102664  0   1   0   2   0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution:**

Simple example with some notes:

- your SQL table doesn't have all combinations, so it is possibe Tec_ID to be undefined
- example uses [PHP Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

**Table (T-SQL script):**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TechnoloieTable] (
    Tec_ID int,
    Tec1 int,
    Tec2 int,
    Tec3 int,
    Tec4 int,
    Tec5 int,
    Tec6 int,
    Tec7 int,
    Tec8 int
)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[TechnoloieTable] 
    (Tec_ID, Tec1, Tec2, Tec3, Tec4, Tec5, Tec6, Tec7, Tec8)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
    (2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
    (3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1),
    (4, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
    (5, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2),
    (6, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2),
    (7, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1),
    (8, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
    (9, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
    (10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2)
```

**HTML (checkbox-table.php):**

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="checkbox-table-submit.php" method="post">

    <table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;" border="1">
    <tbody>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"><strong>Technologie</strong></td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"></td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"></td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">Tec1</td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"><input name="Technoloie[Tec1]" type="checkbox" value="1"/></td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">Tec2</td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"><input name="Technoloie[Tec2]" type="checkbox" value="1"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">Tec3</td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"><input name="Technoloie[Tec3]" type="checkbox" value="1"/></td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">Tec4</td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"><input name="Technoloie[Tec4]" type="checkbox" value="1"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">Tec5</td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"><input name="Technoloie[Tec5]" type="checkbox" value="1"/></td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">Tec6</td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"><input name="Technoloie[Tec6]" type="checkbox" value="1"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">Tec7</td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"><input name="Technoloie[Tec7]" type="checkbox" value="1"/></td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">Tec8</td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"><input name="Technoloie[Tec8]" type="checkbox" value="2"/></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

    <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**PHP (checkbox-table-submit.php):**

```
<?php
// Selection
$selection = array();

// Form selection
if (isset($_POST['Technoloie'])) {
    foreach($_POST['Technoloie'] as $key => $value) {
        $selection[$key] = $value;
    }   
}   
if (empty($selection)) {
    echo 'Make a selection.';
    exit;
}   

// Statement generation.
$sql = "SELECT Tec_ID FROM [dbo].[TechnoloieTable] WHERE ";
foreach ($selection as $field => $value) {
    $sql .= "(".$field."=".$value.")AND";
}   
$sql = substr($sql, 0, strlen($sql)-3);

// Connection with SQLSRV
$server   = 'server\instance,port';
$database = 'database';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$cinfo = array(
    "Database" => $database,
    "UID" => $username,
    "PWD" => $password
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $cinfo);
if ($conn === false) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_connect): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);  
if ($stmt === false) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_connect): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}
$id = 0;
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $id = $row['Tec_ID'];
}
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn);

// Echo ID
echo 'ID: '.$id;
?>
```

**Update:**

If you use PDO, then try to execute your statement with this:

```
// Connection with PDO_SQLSRV
$server   = 'server\instance,port';
$database = 'database';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
try {
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$server;Database=$database", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die("Error connecting to SQL Server".$e->getMessage());
}
try {
    $stmt = $conn->query($sql);
    $id = 0;
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $id = $row['Tec_ID'];
    }   
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die("Error executing query".$e->getMessage());
}
$stmt = null;
$conn = null;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts. Your code would be interesting
<br>
`<input type="checkbox" name="tec[Tec1]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="tec[Tec2]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="tec[Tec3]" value="1" />` 
<br>
this way from Jonathan. Becasue the data just made anonymised.

Comment: @Daniel What you mean - the names of the checkboxes to be an associative array (name="tec[Tec1]")?

Comment: yes the sql column names tec1 = "Flash" and for example the tec2 columns name = "DRAM"

Comment: @Daniel Updated answer.

Comment: `echo $sql;  
exit;  
  
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($connection, $sql);  
//$stmt->execute();  
if ($stmt === false){  
 echo "Error ($connection): ".print_r(sqlsrv_error(), true);  
 exit;  
}  
  
$id = 0;  
var_dump($id);  
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){  
 $id = $row['Tec_ID'];  
}  
var_dump($id);  
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);  
echo $id;  `
  
thx the echo $sql works fine, but i dont get an echo for the $id, what could be the problem?

Comment: @Daniel Sorry, typing error. I've updated the answer and I've removed echo $sql; exit;. Try now.

Comment: still no echo $id

Comment: still no echo oder var_dump

$id = 0;
var_dump($id);
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
 $id = $row['Tec_ID'];
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
var_dump($id);
echo $id;

Comment: @Daniel Updated answer - changed statement generation. SQL statement checks for only selected items. And what are the possible values for all 'Tec' columns - 0 and 1?

Comment: one Tec Column (Tec8) can get the value 0, 1 or 2.

Comment: @Daniel OK. And can you try to execute generated SQL statement in SQL Server Management Studio and post the output?

Comment: SQL Code:
SELECT Tec_ID FROM tec WHERE Tec1 = 1 AND Tec2=1 AND Tec3=1 AND Tec4=0 AND Tec5=1 AND Tec6=0 AND Tec7=0 AND Tec0=0
Output: Tec_ID = 4
PHP Echo: SELECT Tec_ID FROM tec WHERE Tec1 = 0 AND Tec2=0 AND Tec3=0 AND Tec4=0 AND Tec5=0 AND Tec6=0 AND Tec7=0 AND Tec0=0 Tec1 = 1 AND Tec2=1 AND Tec3=1 AND Tec4=0 AND Tec5=1 AND Tec6=0 AND Tec7=0 AND Tec0=0
Without ur SQL stmt if ($value == 1) becasue it can be value 2
sry dont know how to format the comments right.

Comment: i added if($value == 1 || $value == 2) but i still get dont the echo from $id

Comment: thx for the update, can u explain me what 
$sql = substr($sql, 0, strlen($sql)-3); does?
and does it makes a difference when i dont create the static table and use my table instead with a additionally column? (updated)
and what is PHP Driver for SQL Server for? how i can check my server if i use one of this drivers? normaly i can talk to my server over php yet.

Comment: i get echo make selection, but not the // Echo ID
echo 'ID: '.$id;

Comment: @Daniel 1) $sql = substr($sql, 0, strlen($sql)-3); removes final AND (last 3 chars) from generated statement. 2) Statement for table creation is from my test case. You will use your own table - there must be a table somewhere. From question's taq I assume, that you use MS SQL Server as a database, that's way I've made a test with PHP Driver for SQL (sqlsrv extension in php). Run <?phpinfo();?> in simple php file and check if sqlsrv section exists in the output. Thanks.

Comment: @Daniel And I think, that you must be able to echo $sql; before connection section - this will print a valid T-SQL statement. So, you must test the connection with the database and statement execution.

Comment: I call my connection on the start of my php:
<?php
   error_reporting(0);
    $hostname = '';
    $username = '';
    $password = '';
$connection = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$hostname;Database=Masterarbeit", 
             $username, $password);
    if($connection){echo '';}else{echo 'Verbindung fehlgeschlagen<br />';die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),TRUE));}
?>

Comment: i have a sqlsrv part but sqlsupport and enabled are empty just something in Derective, Local Value and Master value

Comment: Error executing querySQLSTATE[22018]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Fehler beim Konvertieren des varchar-Wertes 'SMT' in den int-Datentyp.      The 'SMT' is one Tec, error in converting into int

Comment: @Daniel Try with this: $sql .= "(".$field."='".$value."')AND"; - added single quotes around $value.

Comment: with single quote and double quote i get error, only with single quote i get ID on all clicks 0 . ive updated the original table, SAP column is nvarchar.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your inputs would need to be an associative array because otherwise you won't know which value '1' relates to which 'Tec'.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="tec[Tec1]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="tec[Tec2]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="tec[Tec3]" value="1" />
...
```

Checkboxes only get posted when they are checked, so in PHP you can:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tec WHERE 1=1 "; //WHERE 1=1 is a nice 'hack' so you can have *none* or many AND statements.
foreach($_POST['tec'] as $key => $value) {
    $sql .= "AND $key > 0 "; //Make sure to sanitise your data!!!
    //We can do this because checkboxes are only posted if they're ticked
}

$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if(count($rows) == 1) {
    $my_found_tec_id = $rows[0]['Tec_ID'];
}

//if count is not equal to 1, then do something else... question just talked about 1 match.
```